# Generate csv from nested json python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have following nested json file, which I need to convert in pandas dataframe, the main problem is there is only one unique item in the whole json and it is very deeply nested.

I tried to solve this problem with the following code, but it gives repeating output.

```
[{
"questions": [{
        "key": "years-age",
        "responseKey": null,
        "responseText": "27",
        "responseKeys": null
    },
    {
        "key": "gender",
        "responseKey": "male",
        "responseText": null,
        "responseKeys": null
    }

],
"transactions": [{
        "accId": "v1BN3o9Qy9izz4Jdz0M6C44Oga0qjohkOV3EJ",
        "tId": "80o4V19Kd9SqqN80qDXZuoov4rDob8crDaE53",
        "catId": "21001000",
        "tType": "80o4V19Kd9SqqN80qDXZuoov4rDob8crDaE53",
        "name": "Online Transfer FROM CHECKING 1200454623",
        "category": [
            "Transfer",
            "Acc Transfer"
        ]
    }

],
"institutions": [{
    "InstName": "Citizens company",
    "InstId": "inst_1",
    "accounts": [{
        "pAccId": "v1BN3o9Qy9izz4Jdz0M6C44Oga0qjohkOV3EJ",
        "pAccType": "depo",
        "pAccSubtype": "check",
        "_id": "5ad38837e806efaa90da4849"
    }]

}]
}]
```

I need to convert this to pandas dataframe as follows:

```
 id                        pAccId                                  tId      

 5ad38837e806efaa90da4849  v1BN3o9Qy9izz4Jdz0M6C44Oga0qjohkOV3EJ   80o4V19Kd9SqqN80qDXZuoov4rDob8crDaE53
```

The main problem I am facing is with the "id" as it very deeply nested which is the only unique key for the json.

here is my code:

```
  import pandas as pd
  import json
  with open('sub.json') as f:
       data = json.load(f)

  csv = ''
  for k in data:
       for t in k.get("institutions"):
           csv += k['institutions'][0]['accounts'][0]['_id']
           csv += "\t"
           csv += k['institutions'][0]['accounts'][0]['pAccId']
           csv += "\t"
           csv += k['transactions'][]['tId']
           csv += "\t"
           csv += "\n"

text_file = open("new_sub.csv", "w")
text_file.write(csv)
text_file.close()
```

Hope above code makes sense, as I am new to python.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Where is your problem / problem description / exception / what you hoped to get solved by asking here? Does your code not work? What is the expected outcome? what is the actual outcome? Please reread over [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - there is a severe lack of context/information here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the JSON file and create a dictionary of account `pAccId` keys mapped to account.
Build the list of transactions as well.

```
with open('sub.json', 'r') as file:
    records = json.load(file)
    accounts = {
       account['pAccId']: account 
       for record in records 
       for institution in record['institutions']
       for account in institution['accounts']
    }
    transactions = (
        transaction 
        for record in records 
        for transaction in record['transactions']
    )
```

Open a csv file. For each transaction, get account for it from the `accounts` dictionary.

```
with open('new_sub.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write('id, pAccId, tId\n')

    for transaction in transactions:
        pAccId = transaction['accId']
        account = accounts[pAccId]
        _id = account['_id']
        tId = transaction['tId']

        file.write(f"{_id}, {pAccId}, {tId}\n")
```

Finally, read csv file to `pandas.DataFrame`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('new_sub.csv')
```

Comment: Getting syntax error while generating csv. I think file.write(f"{_id}, {pAccId}, {tId}\n"), f is causing problem here when removing it, code runs but csv file remains empty.

Comment: f-strings are new in Python 3.6. You can use the normal format strings if you're running a version of Python that is older.